# Shorthand command to remove a dir, while retaining integrity of everything under it?

Tags: apache, unix, command-line

I am working in a unix environment, and I am curious if there is a nifty/shorthand way to do the following.

remove the first of the **foo** directories.

(not: the first foo dir has nothing in it but the subsequent foo dir/* )

```
/directory1/foo/foo/bar/baz/
```

to:

```
/directory1/foo/bar/baz/
```

while keeping the integrity of everything under foo/bar/baz.

I am building a server and I inadvertently created an additional folder.

Of course, I can copy everything from foo/* into another folder, delete everything then grab it and put it back without the first foo. curious if there was a shorthand way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Like `mv /directory1/foo/foo/* /directory1/foo && rmdir /directory1/foo/foo` ??

Comment: the `mv` cmd from Mike should be much faster than copying files. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the inode of foo directories, then unlink the first one, and link the second one in it's place, but I have yet to find a way to link inodes directly with the ln command.

Instead, you could do this:

ln /directory/foo/foo /directory/foonew && unlink /directory/foo/foo && unlink /directory/foo && mv /directory/foonew /directory/foo

Answer (score 0):

`mv /directory1/foo/foo/* /directory1/foo && rmdir /directory1/foo/foo`